# how to make the textfield width to be fixed in editor window script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the default window when opening it , it's showing gameobjects with scripts , each gameobject and the script attached to it.

[image: default]

when I'm typing in the search field for example guid and it's showing the gameobjects with any script that contains in the name guid attached to them the yellow Script label is not directly above the textfields of the script's names.

the problem in this case is when I filter for example typing guid the vertical bar on the right is gone and then the textfields width is getting longer and then the yellow "Script" label is not above the textfields directly:

[image: labelfield "Script" is not directly above the scripts names]

the behavior f the scroll bar is fine so I'm not sure how to handle it.
the style of the window and content I like it but this problem that the textfields width get wider on the width is annoying.

I can't find using google how to make the textfields width property to be shorter if there is no vertical scroll bar.  or maybe there is some other way to make it nicer.

the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using static Unity.VisualScripting.Member;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using log4net.Util;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using static UnityEditor.Experimental.AssetDatabaseExperimental.AssetDatabaseCounters;
using UnityEditor.UI;

public class GameObjectAndScriptName
{
    public GameObject GameObject;
    public string ScriptName;

    public GameObjectAndScriptName(GameObject gameObject, string scriptName)
    {
        GameObject = gameObject;
        ScriptName = scriptName;
    }
}

public class ScriptFinder : EditorWindow
{
    static ScriptFinder window;
    static List<GameObjectAndScriptName> gameObjectAndScriptNames = new List<GameObjectAndScriptName>();
    Vector2 scrollPos;
    static List<int> num = new List<int>();
    static List<string> test = new List<string>();

    [MenuItem("EditorUtility/Script Finder")]
    static void OpenScriptFinder()
    {
        window = (ScriptFinder)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(ScriptFinder), false, "Script Finder");
        window.minSize = new Vector2(700, 700);
        window.maxSize = new Vector2(700, 700);
        gameObjectAndScriptNames.Clear();
        MonoBehaviour[] scripts = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>();
        foreach (MonoBehaviour script in scripts)
        {
            Type scriptType = script.GetType();
            var scope = scriptType.Namespace;
            if (scope == null || !scope.StartsWith("Unity"))
            {
                gameObjectAndScriptNames.Add(new GameObjectAndScriptName(script.gameObject, scriptType.Name));
            }
        }

        Traverse();
    }

    static void Traverse()
    {
        test = new List<string>();
        foreach (UnityEngine.Transform t in UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(UnityEngine.Transform)))
        {
            test.Add(t.name);
            Debug.Log(t.name);
        }
    }

    string searchString;
    void OnGUI()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        GUI.color = Color.white;
        GUILayout.Space(30);
       
        searchString = GUILayout.TextField(searchString, GUI.skin.FindStyle("ToolbarSeachTextField"));
        if (GUILayout.Button("", GUI.skin.FindStyle("ToolbarSeachCancelButton")))
        {
            searchString = "";
            GUI.FocusControl(null);
        }

        GUILayout.Space(15);

        GUIStyle TextFieldStyles = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.textField);
        GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
        GUI.color = Color.white;

        //Value Color
        TextFieldStyles.normal.textColor = Color.white;

        //Label Color
        EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor = Color.yellow;
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("         Overall number of GameObjects in Hierarchy: " + test.Count.ToString());
        EditorGUILayout.Space(10);
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("         GameObject                                                                                 Script");

        GUILayout.Space(5);
        EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor = Color.white;

        scrollPos =
            EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos);

        foreach (GameObjectAndScriptName item in gameObjectAndScriptNames)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                if (item.ScriptName.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 25;
                    EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(counter.ToString(),
                        item.GameObject, typeof(GameObject),
                        true);

                    counter++;
                    foreach (UnityEngine.Transform g in item.GameObject.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<UnityEngine.Transform>())
                    {

                    }

                    num.Add(EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.ScriptName).Length);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 25;
                EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(counter.ToString(), item.GameObject, typeof(GameObject), true);

                num.Add(EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.ScriptName).Length);
                if (counter != gameObjectAndScriptNames.Count)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }

        GUILayout.EndScrollView();
    }
}
```

Tried to implement the searching field with the answer but the filtering making many spaces between the results.

```
string searchString;
    void OnGUI()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        var counterWidth = 32;
        var halfWidth = (position.width - counterWidth) / 2;

        GUILayout.Space(30);
        searchString = GUILayout.TextField(searchString, GUI.skin.FindStyle("ToolbarSeachTextField"));
        if (GUILayout.Button("", GUI.skin.FindStyle("ToolbarSeachCancelButton")))
        {
            searchString = "";
            GUI.FocusControl(null);
        }

        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        {
            GUILayout.Space(counterWidth + 6);
            GUILayout.Label($"GameObject", GUILayout.Width(halfWidth));
            GUILayout.Label($"Script", GUILayout.Width(halfWidth));
        }
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos);
        {
            foreach (GameObjectAndScriptName item in gameObjectAndScriptNames)
            {
                GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                {
                    counter++;
                    EditorGUILayout.LabelField(counter.ToString(), GUILayout.Width(counterWidth));
                    if (searchString != null)
                    {
                        if (item.ScriptName.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(item.GameObject, typeof(GameObject), true, GUILayout.Width(halfWidth));
                            EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.ScriptName);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(item.GameObject, typeof(GameObject), true, GUILayout.Width(halfWidth));
                        EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.ScriptName);
                    }
                }
                GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            }
        }
        GUILayout.EndScrollView();
    }
```

result:

[image: filter search]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positioning of the labels should be in a Horizontal layout.  Then you can specify the width of those labels.

Use the windows width (`position.width`) to calculate the size of the controls.
Use `GUILayout.Width` to set the width on the control.

```
var counterWidth = 32;
var halfWidth = (position.width - counterWidth) / 2;

GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
{
    GUILayout.Space(counterWidth + 6);
    GUILayout.Label($"GameObject", GUILayout.Width(halfWidth));
    GUILayout.Label($"Script", GUILayout.Width(halfWidth));
}
GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos);
{
    foreach (GameObjectAndScriptName item in gameObjectAndScriptNames)
    {
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField(counter.ToString(), GUILayout.Width(counterWidth));
            EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(item.GameObject, typeof(GameObject), true, GUILayout.Width(halfWidth));
            EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.ScriptName);
        }
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }
}
GUILayout.EndScrollView();
```

To get the two conditions to display the items, create a function that draws the item and pass the missing parameters to it.

```
private void GUI_DrawItem(GameObjectAndScriptName item, int counter, float counterWidth, float controlWidth)
{
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    {
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField(counter.ToString(), GUILayout.Width(counterWidth));
        EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(item.GameObject, typeof(GameObject), true, GUILayout.Width(controlWidth));
        EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.ScriptName);
    }
    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
}
```

Use case:

```
if (searchString != null)
{
    if (item.ScriptName.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        GUI_DrawItem(item, ++counter, counterWidth, halfWidth);
    }
}
else
{
    GUI_DrawItem(item, ++counter, counterWidth, halfWidth);
}
```

Comment: How to implement the searching filter part? I edited my question with what I tried with your answer but when filtering in the search field the results are with many spaces between each textfield.

Comment: It looks like its caused by the counter label field being outside of the contains condition.  I think in this case you have to duplicate that line.  Add one inside of the contains condition and one in the else block.   Add the counter++ to both.

Comment: working thanks.  I had to move inside in both places also the counter++;  and also the line that I forgot to move inside in both places: EditorGUILayout.LabelField(counter.ToString(), GUILayout.Width(counterWidth));

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you can do this with a function instead of copy pasting those sections of code.  I usually put all the different sections of gui into functions, but that is a matter of preference.  In this case a function is preferred.

Comment: working great.  last question , how can I change the text color of the $"GameObject" and the $"Script" I want them both to be in yellow. only this two lables to be in yellow.

Comment: I usually use GUI.color.  eg. `var color = GUI.color;  GUI.color = Color.yellow; ... GUI.color = color;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253725/discussion-between-hijinxbassist-and-jdoedoe-doedoe).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you have at least two options:

- The first one is the simplest one - you can force your vertical scrollbar to be shown always. Check `EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView` for this. However, as for me, it is not the prettiest one =)
- The second option is more complicated. You can calculate all the element sizes without `EditorGUILayout`. In this case, you can make your scroll view size fixed and then you will be able to determine, what minimum amount of elements will force a vertical scrollbar to appear.